# Icon not displayed inside input line in Ionic 3

Tags: input, ionic2, icons, ionic3

I have the following code in my Ionic 3 project.

```
<ion-item>
  <ion-icon name="person" item-start></ion-icon>
  <ion-label floating>Email</ion-label>
  <ion-input type="email" name="email" [(ngModel)]="registerCredentials.email" required></ion-input>
</ion-item>
```

This gives me the following result.
[image]

The icon in outside of the input line. Who to get it inside by keeping my Label floating.

Answer (score 1):

You can fix that by placing the icon inside of the label, like this:

```
<ion-item>      
  <ion-label floating>
    <ion-icon name="person" item-start></ion-icon> // <--- Here!
    Email
  </ion-label>
  <ion-input type="email" name="email" [(ngModel)]="registerCredentials.email" required></ion-input>
</ion-item>
```

**[Working plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/3MfuFqVtLHpwMb9uav2h?p=preview)**

**EDIT**

> If I do that the Icon and Label both are floating when the field is
>   selected. Only the label should float up.

In order to prevent that, you can add the following style rule:

```
ion-item.input-has-focus ion-label[floating] ion-icon,
ion-item.input-has-value ion-label[floating] ion-icon {
    display: none;
}
```

That way the icon will be shown only when the label *is not floating*.

**EDIT II**

> It's working they way you want it to work but my solution will be the Icon should remain visible in the box and the label will float. Is that possible?

You could add a few style rules to do that. The key would be to place the icon outside the `ion-label`, and set its position to be an `absolute` value. Please take a look at this **[new updated plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/tSSszrqYvMZOk4LQfZD4?p=preview)**

The result would be like this:

[image: placeholder demo]

**html**

```
  <ion-item>      
    <ion-icon name="person" item-start></ion-icon>
    <ion-label floating>
      Email
    </ion-label>
    <ion-input type="email" name="email" required></ion-input>
  </ion-item>
```

**scss**

```
ion-item {
  position: relative;
}

ion-item.item-label-floating .text-input {
  margin-left: 32px;
  width: calc(100% - 32px);
}

ion-item.item-input ion-icon {
  display: flex;
  align-items: flex-end;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 44px;
  color: #7f7f7f;
  font-size: 24px;
  min-width: 0 !important;
  text-align: left !important;
}


ion-item.item-input ion-label[floating] {
      padding-left: 32px;
}

ion-item.input-has-focus ion-label[floating],
ion-item.input-has-value ion-label[floating] {
  pading-left: 0;
  transform: translate3d(-25.6px, 0, 0) scale(0.8); /* 25.6 is equal to 32 * 0.8 (the scale factor) */
}
```

Comment: If I do that the Icon and Label both are floating when the field is seleced. Only the label should float up.

Comment: I've updated the answer, please let me know if it works on your end

Comment: It's working they way you want it to work but my solution will be the Icon should remain visible in the box and the label will float. Is that possible?

Comment: That's a great help. It's working but there are 2 issues. CSS is not working for ios. I could not make it happen. Also in android the input fields are not in the center. There is more space on the left.