# Floating label not aligned with input in Ionic 2

Tags: ionic-framework, input, sass, ionic2, label

In my Ionic2 project when using the floating label, it is not correctly aligned with the input box. How can I fix this?

[image]

Following is the code:

```
<ion-item>
  <ion-label floating><ion-icon name="person" item-start></ion-icon>Email</ion-label>
  <ion-input type="email" name="email" [(ngModel)]="registerCredentials.email"></ion-input>
</ion-item>
```

This is not a duplicate question. The one it is compared to is about keeping the label floating and icon fixed. This is an alignment related question.

Comment: You asked the same question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46134832/icon-not-displayed-inside-input-line-in-ionic-3/46134875?noredirect=1#comment79338102_46134875). **Please don't post several questions with the same content**

Answer (score 0):

could you please share the code?

If you use the ion-item and ion-label like this, the text is correctly aligned:

```html
<ion-item>
  <ion-label floating>Username</ion-label>
  <ion-input></ion-input>
</ion-item>
```

[Input no selected](https://i.stack.imgur.com/n5G5d.jpg)

[Input Selected](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ccBRK.jpg)

Comment: ion-icon is extra here. I check without it is aligned. How can I do it with the icon?